# How to measure a non-integer number of periods of a sine wave signal using harmonic analysis

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, wavelets

Given a signal, f(t), with a non-integer number of periods of a sine wave, is there some way to measure the correct number of periods using some kind of harmonic analysis (fourier transforms, wavelets, etc...)?

For example, let's say that I have a signal f(t) = sin(t) with t = [0,3pi].  Is there any kind of transform or technique that will correctly identify this as a sine wave with 1.5 periods?

(The regular Fourier transform of the entire signal won't do the job because it assumes that the signal is made up of complete periods of cosines and sines.)